# One to one Modeling?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy

What do you guys think of this model?

```
Catalog -< Catalog Items | - | Products
```

and

```
Catalog -< Catalog Items | - | Services
```

That is, a `Catalog Item`, can be one and only one type: `Product` or `Service`.

If this is the case, does the relationship end up being a one to one between `Catalog Items` and both the `Products` and `Services` table? And if so, then how would one program to distinguish between which key is related to which table, meaning would it be foreign key plus foreign "string" that identifies either table? How can I guarantee it would be a one-to-one?